# Visual Studio can only select android-25 target API for native activity packaging project

Tags: android, visual-studio-2022, native-activity

I have two issues that I don't really understand:

1. The visual studio installer only lets you select android-25 or android-31, Where are the rest of them?
2. Even with 31 installed, the native activity packaging application only lets you select android-25

The other C++ android projects can select the andoid-30 target (and pretty much anything up to 30) even though that's not even installed.
[image]

VS Installer:
[image]
I need to be able to target api 30.